# Разбить таблицу на секции по N записей

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, есть таблица-куча без каких либо ключей.

Есть колонка, которая  определяет принадлежность N-го кол-ва записей к конкретной секции.

У первых N записей там 1, у вторых N записей там 2, и т д.

На ум приходит цикл `WHILE`, где бы обновлялись `TOP N` колонок `WHERE` PartNum `IS NULL`.

Как можно это сделать с минимальным числом обновлений? Может быть оконные функции могут это сделать? Мало с ними работал...

Comment: `У первых N записей там 1, у вторых N записей там 2` это про `NTILE(N) over( order by col1)`, но что то смысл задачи не совсем ясен

Comment: Вроде, то что нужно.

Comment: еще в этом смысле приходит на ум нумерация строк и деление на цело на N

Comment: Смысл задачи в том, что бы потом с этой кучей было легче работать прикладному ПО, извлекая и обрабатывая группу за группой.

Comment: ну я про то, что конкретно сделать надо. проапдейтить таблицу, пронумеровав группы?

Comment: Да, в итоге нужно проапдейтить таблицу проставив каждой строке принадлежность к группе.

Comment: а вот и нифига, `ntile` не каждые N нумерует, а общее число записей делит на N групп. можно конечно подобрать нужное значение. То есть N определяет число групп, а не элементов в группе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

поскольку мой вариант из комментариев про `NTILE` оказался ошибочен (*`NTILE` разбивает набор на N-групп, а не на группы по N-строк* ), то второй был с обычным делением нацело.

Исходные:

```
declare @t table (id int, gr int null);
insert into @t (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

declare @n int = 2;

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

и апдейт через `CTE`

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, gr
          ,( row_number() over (order by id) -1 )/@n AS num
    FROM @t 
)
UPDATE cte SET gr = num;

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

очевидный результат

```
id          gr
----------- -----------
1           0
2           0
3           1
4           1
5           2
```