# Поделить строки на подгруппы

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Подскажите, как можно поделить строки на подгруппы нужного размера?

Скажем, на имеется группа из 6 строк и я хочу, что бы группы были поделены на подгруппы по 4 строчки.

Т.е в итоге получается 4 строки в одной группе, а 2 остальные образуют 2-ую неполноценную группу.

Пробовал NTILE использовать, но он работает немного не так, как мне нужно, так как если ему на вход передать 2, то он создаст 2 подгруппы по 3.

На вход подается таблица такого вида:

```
IDGroup|IDPerson
```

Эти 2 поля являются составным ключем.

IDGroup вот нужно поделить на подгруппы.

Comment: был подобный вопрос уже, кажется вы и задавали.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разбить таблицу на секции по N записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732758/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-n-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: в общем в два захода, сначала посчитать размер группы (общее число записей делить на желаемый размер группы), и его уже использовать в `ntile`.

Comment: @teran Похоже, но немного другое. Я дополнил вопрос и ответ дал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я вот так хитро сделал:

```
UPDATE p
    SET p.GrpID=ISNULL((SELECT GrpId FROM (
                                    SELECT IDGroup,
                                    IdPerson,
                                    NTILE(MultiplicityGrpCount) OVER(Partition by IDGroup order by IDGroup,IdPerson) GrpId
                                    FROM (

                                            SELECT TOP(MultiplicityRecordCount) * FROM #Proc p2
                                            WHERE p2.IdGroup=p.IdGroup
                                            ORDER BY IdGroup,IdPerson
                                        ) p2
                                    ) T 
                where t.IdGroup=p.IdGroup and t.IdPerson=p.IdPerson
                ),999999999)
    from #Proc p
    JOIN (SELECT p.IdGroup,COUNT(*) as  AllRecordCount,
            COUNT(*)/@MaxPersonCount*@MaxPersonCount as MultiplicityRecordCount,
            COUNT(*)/@MaxPersonCount as MultiplicityGrpCount  FROM #Proc p
            group by p.IdGroup) t on t.IdGroup=p.IdGroup
```

В данных на вход уже были группы, но в каждой группе требовалось создать подгруппу нужного размера.

Суть в том, что в нижнем подзапросе я высчитываю какое кол-во записей будет кратно кол-ву на которое нужно делить. В самом глубоком подзапросе, я выбираю `TOP` кратного кол-ва и его через `NTILE` делю на подгруппы. Снаружи стоит `ISNULL`, который ставит константу 999999999 тем записям, которые не попали в кратное кол-во- это остаток.